# SQL - How to get Data 2 days in the past and 5 days from a specific date

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I am currently working on a project for fun. There I have besides many other tables 2 specific ones.

[image]

One contains an event that is going to happen or has happened. The other ones contains sales of any item you can imagine lets take tickets in an online ticket store.

I want to look back in the past if the turnover get somehow effected by an event. Therefore I want to look 2 days in Advance before that event happened. And 5 days after the beginning of the event to see its outcome.

My Desired Outcome looks sth. like this:

[image]

This is like the biggest simplification i could come up with, hopefully it is enough.

I've tried sth like this:

```
Where event.Date = values.Date 
or event.Date = values.Date - 2
or event.Date = values.Date - 1 
or event.Date = values.Date + 1
```

... and so on, however its not working, and lets imagine i dont want to go 2 days back in the past and 5 days in the "future" but 90 days and 60 days. That would take a long time to set this up, so I think there should be a smarter Way. Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for linking me to this post, and i thought it would be benefical :D. Won't do it again!

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.date as date_event, e.event, v.date as date_sold, v.sold * v.price
from event as e inner join values as v
    on v.date between e.date - interval '2 days'
                  and e.date + interval '5 days'
```

I may have gotten the PostgreSQL syntax slightly wrong on the date math but you get the idea.